# Browser game protection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have simple JavaScript game with server on node.js. For login I use JWT token. Everything is working well, but I have one problem.

If the user changes the position, variables x and y are sent to API. This is ok, but user can change data in browser webtools and resent them with other values. Of course I have validation on server side, but user can use it to automatic change positions, immediate change etc.

How can I protect it?

On standard app I could generate hash from x and y + salt, but if I pass salt to browser, then the user can get it and generate appropriate hash.

Comment: You cannot protect your game from this on client-side. Limit the position change rate in your API and maybe provide salts / tokens that change from time to time to prevent a trivial script to automate it. But you cannot prevent the user to TRY to trick your system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client's browser is under the clients control. You can't do anything about it. But really, if the client changes the players position, why should that be bad? Whenever he takes any action you should send the position to the server, then validate the position against the previous position. If the distance is too huge, block the fraudster.